# Merge two collection based on 3 column

Tags: mongodb

I want to join two collection called **Emp1** with **salary** based on ***dept,id and name*** . I would like to merge both as we do in pandas merge.

```
Emp1:
{"dept":"cs","id": 100,"name":"xxx","age": 20}
{"dept":"IT","id": 110,"name":"xxx","age": 21}
{"dept":"AI","id": 110,"name":"xxx","age": 21}
```

sal:

```
{"dept":"cs","id": 100,"name":"xxx","sal": 200}
{"dept":"IT","id": 110,"name":"xxx","sal": 2100}
{"dept":"AI","id": 110,"name":"xxx","sal": 2100}
```

The output should look like something below:

```
{"dept":"cs","id": 100,"name":"xxx","age": 20,"sal":200}
{"dept":"IT","id": 110,"name":"xxx","age": 21,"sal": 2100}
{"dept":"AI","id": 110,"name":"xxx","age": 21,"sal": 2100}
```

What will be best solution to join based on 3 columns. I understand we can use lookup operation, But the case here is to join based on 3 column..

Comment: What code have you tried for this so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipeline in lookup to do multiple joins as below:
Here firstly you assign your keys to be matched in let and in pipleine $match you can only use $expr to use conditional operator and lastly we merge the $lookup result with part of the $$ROOT document using the $mergeObjects operator.

```
db.emp.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sal",
      let: {
        dept: "$dept",
        id: "$id",
        name: "$name"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$dept",
                    "$$dept"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$id",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$name",
                    "$$name"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "result"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$result",
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            age: "$$ROOT.age"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Awsome..I wasnt aware of this kind of usage..thanks